# jsTree create_node callback function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

Using jsTree, when adding a node to my tree using the **`create_node`** function, I am attempting to add a callback function, as per https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/v.1.0/dist/jstree.js#L3549 .

However, it does not seem to execute, as illustrated here--> http://jsfiddle.net/thapar/e3nMg/ when **`Add Root Item`** is clicked (expecting `console.log()` to say "hi", in the very least).

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation at http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core, it looks like the 'callback' parameter to the `.create_node` function is used internally. It states that you should instead listen for the event. You can do so like this (assuming you're using the same code as in your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thapar/e3nMg/) post:

```
$('.colors').bind('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
   console.log('hi', data.rslt.obj);
});
```

​

Answer (score 4):

jstree version 3, there is a create_node event:

"triggered when a node is created":

http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=.jstree%20Event&f=create_node.jstree

```
$(function() {
    var $root = $('#jstree').jstree({
        "core" : {
            check_callback : true
        },
        "themes" : {},
        "ui" : {},
        "plugins" : [ "dnd", "state","themes", "html_data", "ccrm", "ui" ],

    });     

    $('#jstree').on('create_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
        console.log('hi', data);
    });

    $('#add_root').click(function() {
        $root.jstree(true).create_node($root, "sub4");
    });
})
```